IntelliJ/Rider - Can I adjust Reformat Code to only affect changed lines on the Git Option?
I love the "Reformat code" feature on Jetbrains IDE's Git menu because it allows me not to worry about it while I code and doing it automatically.

However, it applies to the whole files in the commit and I would like to do it only on changed lines. The reason being that it makes it more difficult for others to review my code.
I know there is a dialog for this if I run through CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + L but I was wondering if it's possible to do it via Git.

No, unfortunately, that's not possible, but I'd love it, too. Maybe you can file a feature request here?
